# kubernetes/client-go undefined: v1.FinalizerOrphan

Tags: go, kubernetes

I get the go get k8s.io/client-go/1.5/...
An error occurred while trying to go run:

```
> # k8s.io/client-go/pkg/api/v1
> ../k8s.io/client-go/pkg/api/v1/helpers.go:86: undefined: v1.FinalizerOrphan
```

Want to how to deal with, please?

../k8s.io/client-go/pkg/api/v1/helpers.go:86:

```golang
var standardFinalizers = sets.NewString(
    string(FinalizerKubernetes),
    metav1.FinalizerOrphan,
)
```

Comment: How did you install the dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue when I tried to go get kubernetes v1.5.2.
Just solved it with:
  *cd ../k8s.io/kubernetes*
  *git checkout v1.5.2*

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this should be temporary--we are working on a fix (and on a system so our publishing bot stops breaking the client). In the meantime, go back a commit or two, as the other answer suggests.